# Migration from meta to main site gives wrong 'migration text'

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

The question [Is TeX as word and logo a trade mark?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30326/is-tex-as-word-and-logo-a-trade-mark#question) was migrated from Meta to the main site. However, the banner that is added says:

> migrated from meta.tex.stackexchange.com x hours ago
>
> This question came from our site for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and
>   related typesetting systems.

This is not really right: it should say its come from *discussion about* TeX.sx.

Comment: This problem's still there: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36575/autorefs-inserted-text-has-not-the-correct-case. Perhaps this question should be migrated to [metase]? This kind of bugs usually gets fixed pretty quickly over there.

Comment: @doncherry So it is: very odd.

Comment: Btw, this problem appears for questions migrated to [metase] as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97964/profile-data-visibility

Comment: I posted the question to [metase]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116970/162565

Comment: The answer is posted here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117250/2

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Great, thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now fixed, as Geoff indicates. (I'm posting a CW answer so that I can mark the question as answered in a little while.)